# how to load html page in ajax success function and load values to html page

Tags: jquery, html

I'm not able to load html page in ajax success function. I'm not able to load response values to page.
i'm using Windows.locate to load html page.

```
var groupName = data.groupName;
                var firstname= data.firstname;
                var lastname= data.lastname;
                $('#firstname').val(firstname);
                $('#serviceName').val(data.lastname);
               window.location = "url";
```

But i'm not getting values in html page.
thank you.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to achieve. I assume `data` is returned in your `ajax.success` handler? But then you are navigating to another page using `window.location`. Do you want the values in `data` to be propagated to the next page?

Comment: yes i don't know how to do.

Comment: Then you can't use window.location, as this does a GET. See answer I will post in a second.

Comment: The first line of your question is in code tag, it's confusing and hard to read. It'd be better if you make it normal text

Answer (score 0):

You need to POST to the url. So the inputs `#firstname`, `#lastname` need to be in a form and you need to submit the form to `url`. So in jQuery:

```
$("#formId").submit();
```

Or you can use: `$.post(url, data);` See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Then, on the server, you should have the values contained in `data` and can set the firstname and lastname server-side.

Comment: sorry i did't get.. i had one button in first html page by clicking that i'm calling ajax and in success function i'm calling second html page along with response values. firstname and last name are two text box in second html page..

Comment: What I mean is, when you call `window.location` it's a GET. So you would need to add your values to the url's querystring to pass them to the other page. The way you are doing it, you need to POST using a `<form>` or `jQuery.post()`. If firstname and lastname are in the page you are about to call, you can't do this from the first page as these elements don't exist.

Comment: By the way, this is a peculiar way of doing things, unless you're making a decision in the first page's `ajax.success()` method whether to post to the second page or do something else. Why not just post immediately to the second page, and that page can get firstname and lastname?

Answer (score -2):

1.

```
$(selector).load(URL,data,callback);
$("button").click(function(){
  $("#div1").load("demo_test.txt",function(responseTxt,statusTxt,xhr){
    if(statusTxt=="success")
       alert("External content loaded successfully!");
    if(statusTxt=="error")
      alert("Error: "+xhr.status+": "+xhr.statusText);
  });
});
```

2.

```
$.get(URL,callback);
$("button").click(function(){
  $.get("demo_test.php",function(data,status){
    alert("Data: " + data + "nStatus: " + status);
  });
});

demo_test.php
<?php
echo "This is some text from an external PHP file.";
?>
```

3.

```
$.post(URL,data,callback);
$("button").click(function(){
  $.post("demo_test_post.html",
  {
    name:"Donald Duck",
    city:"Duckburg"
  },
  function(data,status){
    alert("Data: " + data + "nStatus: " + status);
  });
});

<?php
$name = isset($_POST['name']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']) : '';
$city = isset($_POST['city']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['city']) : '';
echo 'Dear ' . $name;
echo 'Hope you live well in ' . $city;
?>
```